# How to increase the number of frames that Android dumpsys gfxinfo can record?

Tags: android, opengl-es, performance-testing, gfx

I'm using command "dumpsys gfxinfo package.name" to record the performance data of my application. I noted that it can only record 128 frames for "Draw","Process", and "execute". I want to automatically run the application for minutes or so and record those OGL data. Is there any way I can do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a simple script which will fetch it for you every 100ms for example.

Once you fetch data it's frees it's buffer.